# Title of page does not reflect suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, question-titles

The title of the page (the text on the tab) should reflect the post with the proposed edits, not the original version. E.g., this question should display `Snap store isn't installing` as the title of the page, instead of `Pls somebody help why...`.

Here is a screenshot of the issue
[image: Screenshot of inconsistancy]

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug exactly. When you suggest an edit, you and you alone see a preview of the edited page but the actual page doesn't change until approval, so the page at that address absolutely still gives the original title and not the edited one. That's not to say they won't change it, if they can, just I don't know if it is a bug per say.

Comment: @MarkKirby I meant just for the person that did the edit, not for everyone. The code to update if it was edited could even run client side (see if the proposed edit box exists, if so, change the page title).